# Any known Vulnerabilities in RxJS 5

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

Trying to understand if RxJs can be used safely in production. 
Anyone knows about Vulnerabilities in RxJS 5. 
Are the below issues known with RxJS5. Please help.

```
**Vulnerabilities - Public Data**
CVE-2017-1000048 High Risk Prototype Override Protection Bypass qs 2.4.2
CVE-2015-8855 High Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) semver 2.3.2
CVE-2017-1000048 High Risk Prototype Override Protection Bypass qs 5.2.1
CVE-2017-1000048 High Risk Prototype Override Protection Bypass qs 2.3.3
CVE-2017-15010 Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) Via Parsing Cookies tough-cookie 2.3.2
CVE-2017-15010 Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) Via Parsing Cookies tough-cookie 2.2.2

**Vulnerabilities - Premium Data**
RESERVED (CVE-2016-1000023) High Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) minimatch 0.3.0
RESERVED (CVE-2016-1000023) High Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) minimatch 2.0.10
NO-CVE High Risk Remote Code Execution (RCE) growl 1.9.2
RESERVED (CVE-2016-1000023) High Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) minimatch 2.0.4
NO-CVE Medium Risk Insecure Cipher request 2.55.0
NO-CVE Medium Risk Remote Memory Disclosure request 2.55.0
NO-CVE Medium Risk Insecure Cipher request 2.67.0
NO-CVE Medium Risk Remote Memory Disclosure request 2.67.0
RESERVED (CVE-2016-2515) Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) hawk 2.3.1
NO-CVE Medium Risk Insecure Cipher request 2.79.0
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) debug 2.6.8
NO-CVE Medium Risk Insecure Cipher request 2.81.0
NO-CVE Medium Risk Denial Of Service (DoS) ws 1.1.5
NO-CVE Medium Risk Timing Attacks http-signature 0.10.1
NO-CVE Medium Risk Arbitrary Command Injection shelljs 0.7.6
RESERVED (CVE-2016-1000013) Medium Risk Cross-site Scripting (XSS) Due To Sanitization Bypass Using HTML Entities marked 0.3.5
NO-CVE Medium Risk Cross-site Scripting (XSS) marked 0.3.5
NO-CVE Medium Risk Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) marked 0.3.5
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) marked 0.3.5
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) debug 2.2.0
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) ms 0.7.3
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) ms 0.7.1
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) debug 2.6.6
NO-CVE Medium Risk Information Disclosure tunnel-agent 0.4.3
NO-CVE Medium Risk Regular Expression Denial Of Service (ReDoS) Via Long String Of Semicolons tough-cookie 2.2.2
```

Comment: RxJS has only one non-dev dependency: `symbol-observable`. Any 'vulerabilities' in dev dependencies aren't relevant regarding production use of RxJS.

Comment: To make it clear, the question is on RxJS itself. For example if you create a new project with angular cli it adds the RxJS as a "dependency" in package.json.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The report given to me got reverted back, saying some issue on how the SourceClear was run.

No Vulnerabilities are found in RxJS. All Good.

The new report came back with Zero (0) Vulnerabilities.